# Steps in Hosting WCF service i IIS(5.1)

Tags: sql-server

I have create a WCF Service and hosted the Service in IIS (5.1).

I have used basicHttpbinding and wsHttpBinding.Follwoing is the config declaration of binding.

```
<service name="ServiceLibarary.DummyService" behaviorConfiguration="mexHttp">
   <endpoint address="Soap11" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ServiceLibarary.IService" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp"/>
   <endpoint address="Soap12" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ServiceLibarary.IService" bindingConfiguration="wsHttp"/>
   <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
</service>
```

and respective binding configuration

```
<bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="basicHttp">
         <readerQuotas/>
         <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
         </security>
      </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
   <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="wsHttp">
         <security mode="None">
            <message clientCredentialType="None" />
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
         </security>
      </binding>
   </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I have created ASP.MVC web app as client. I have Linq-to-Sql clasess in the `Service` project. The problem is when I am running the client (MVC App) and tying to login, I am getting

> *Cannot open database "WCF" requested by the login. The login failed.Login failed for user  error.*

Where `WCF` is the name of the database.

I am initialising the proxy class at client with basic binding.

When I add service reference from same solution i.e taking service reference from solution in which WCF service build (same as MVC app) , it is working fine.
Following is the connectionString which i have

```
   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ServiceLibarary.Properties.Settings.WCFConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=WCF;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I am using Window XP and .NET 3.5.
Any idea why is it happening? Am I missing something.

Comment: There is no database code in your example. None of this code could have cause that exception.

Comment: Furthermore, which version of Windows are you running? Is this Windows XP? Which version of .NET are you using? Are you using a version of .NET which is not supported on that version of Windows?

Comment: Your ASP.NET MVC app is now trying to connect to your database with the credentials it's using to run - typically something like `IUSER_(machine)` or `NETWORK SERVICE`. Do these "users" have access to your database?? Tip: create a separate, app-specific SQL Server login and grant it the necessary permissions, and then use that specific user (and password) in your connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a WCF configuration issue, this is a Database/Connection String issue.

The connection string is pointing to a local database which is not accessible in this configuration.

```
Data Source=localhost;
```

You need to modify the connection string accordingly or check the configuration of the database, whichever is applicable to your environment.

It looks to me that the remote machine does have a database server running, but it either does not have the corresponding 'WCF' database, or the username/password is incorrect.

Comment: Chris, Client and Service is hosted on same machine.

Comment: @NirajChoubey  Are the client and service using the same app pool? You are using integrated security and the users may differ?